Instantiating items from a UI in a different scene
I have a pachinko style game with varying balls that have unique characteristics. I want to allow the player to create a loadout of what types of balls they would like to use before they enter the game scene and this would happen in a separate loadout scene.
I'm having trouble on 2 points:

The reference is being returned as null and thus when I enter the game scene, it crashes with an error stating such

The SaveLoad system isn't recording the items in each loadout slot, though I suppose this is a different issue.


Here is the code for each script involved in this process:
Game attached to an empty GameObject in each scene
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    [HideInInspector] public ulong highestScore = 0; 
    [HideInInspector] public ulong totalCurrentCredits = 0; 
    [HideInInspector] public string playerName = " "; 
    [HideInInspector] public short ballSlotsUnlocked = 5; 
    [HideInInspector] public string[] ballSetAssigned = new string[20]; 
    [HideInInspector] public List<GameObject> slots;

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                ballSetAssigned[i] = slots[i].GetComponent<EquipmentSlot>().GetBallName();
                Debug.Log(ballSetAssigned[i] + " From gameObject " + gameObject.name + " inside " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log($"null from Game Awake at index {i}");
                continue;
            }
    
        }
    }
    
    public void SaveGame()
    {
        SaveLoad.SaveGame(this);
    }
    
    public void LoadGame()
    {
        GameData gameData = SaveLoad.LoadGame();
        highestScore = gameData.highestScore;
        totalCurrentCredits = gameData.totalCurrentCredits;
        playerName = gameData.playerName;
        ballSlotsUnlocked = gameData.ballSlotsUnlocked;
        for (int i = 0; i < ballSetAssigned.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ballSetAssigned[i] == null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} reporting in: ballSetAssigned at index {i} is null. moving on");
                continue;
            }
            ballSetAssigned[i] = gameData.ballSetAssigned[i];
        }
    }
}

GameData static class to hold Serializable data through the SaveLoad class
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    public ulong highestScore = 0;
    public ulong totalCurrentCredits = 0;
    public string playerName = " ";
    public short ballSlotsUnlocked = 5;
    public string[] ballSetAssigned = new string[20];
    
    public GameData(Game game)
    {
        highestScore = game.highestScore;
        totalCurrentCredits = game.totalCurrentCredits;
        playerName = game.playerName;
        ballSlotsUnlocked = game.ballSlotsUnlocked;

        for (int i = 0; i < ballSetAssigned.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {

                ballSetAssigned[i] = game.ballSetAssigned[i];
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log($"null at {i}");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

SaveLoad static class responsible for serializing and deserializing data. Copied from Brackeys.
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveLoad
{
    public static void SaveGame(Game game)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf  = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedGameData.gd";
        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        GameData gameData = new GameData(game);
        bf.Serialize(file, gameData);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static GameData LoadGame()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedGameData.gd";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            GameData gameData = (GameData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            return gameData;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

EquipmentSlot attached to each GameObject named slot in the UI Canvas in the loadout scene. Also attached to the viewport of a scroll view for moving DraggableItems to and from equipped to inventory.
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class EquipmentSlot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public static string slotName;
    Game game;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!gameObject.name.Contains("View"))
        {
            game = GameObject.Find("GameDataManager").GetComponent<Game>();
            game.slots.Add(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(transform.childCount == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                GameObject dropped = eventData.pointerDrag;
                DraggableItem draggableItem = dropped.GetComponent<DraggableItem>();
                draggableItem.parentAfterDrag = transform;
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(transform.name == "Viewport") 
        {
            try
            {
                GameObject dropped = eventData.pointerDrag;
                DraggableItem draggableItem = dropped.GetComponent<DraggableItem>();
                Debug.Log(draggableItem.parentAfterDrag);
                Debug.Log(transform);
                draggableItem.parentAfterDrag = transform;

            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //Leftover from previous attempts, may be useful later.
    int GetSlotIndex()
    {
        if(transform.name.Length == 13)
        {
            string indexCharacters = transform.name[transform.name.Length - 2].ToString() + transform.name[transform.name.Length - 1].ToString();
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(indexCharacters);
            return index;
        }
        else if(transform.name.Length == 12)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(transform.name[transform.name.Length - 1].ToString());
            return index;
        }

        return 0;
    }
  

    public string GetBallName()
    {
        if(transform.childCount > 0)
        {
            return transform.GetComponentInChildren<DraggableItem>().ReferenceBallPathByUIName();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

DraggableItem attached to a UI image that represents the gameObject to be instantiated in the game scene.
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DraggableItem : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    [HideInInspector] public Transform parentAfterDrag;
    public Image image;
    public string imageName;
    
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        parentAfterDrag = transform.parent;
        transform.SetParent(transform.root);
        transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        image.raycastTarget = false;
        imageName = gameObject.name;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.SetParent(parentAfterDrag);
        image.raycastTarget = true;
    }

    public string ReferenceBallPathByUIName()
    {
        switch(transform.name)
        {
            case "BombBallUIElement": return "Prefabs/Balls/Inactive/InactiveBombBall.prefab";
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Initially tried to serialize an array of GameObjects but unity wasnt having it. I then changed the array to string and have tried many variations of code to get the gameData to save the data represented in a full slot and ignore the empty ones. This is currently what I have ended up on without breaking the SaveLoad system.
Ideally, the system should read the UI image, in this case "BombBallUIElement", from the slot through the equipment script which adds to the list of strings in Game.
The list would then be read and if any reference returns a balls name which is its path in assets, then it'll be saved into a local GameObject variable through Resources.Load(ballSetAssigned[index]) and then Instantiated.

in general STOP using BinaryFormatter!

First of all, you are trying to access the slots list in the Game Awake() method which has not been initialized.
The simplest way to fix this would be to change the declaration to:
[HideInInspector] public List<GameObject> slots = new List<GameObject>();

And I really need to mention that the way you are handling errors here isn't the greatest.
You have try catch blocks which output things like:
Debug.Log($"null from Game Awake at index {i}");

Which assumes that the only error that will be thrown in the try block will be a null reference, which is not necessarily true.
You should output the actual error by doing something like this:
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log($"An error ocurred when assigning ball slots:\n{e}");
}

If you really want to have a custom message for the case of a null ref then you can check if the Exception type is of NullReferenceException.
Though your message is unnecessary as the exception itself will tell you where it happens and even link you to the line of code.
As for serializing an array of GameObjects, this unfortunately doesn't work with the built-in binary formatter. You can get around this by using JSON or XML serialization.
Though keep in mind, Unity's default way of serializing GameObject is to store the InstanceID which is not very useful for persistent data between runs of the app.
I know some people get around this by generating UUIDs for the objects, though I've recently used a system that stored asset references in a ScriptableObject and generated my own object IDs to serialize. Just to give you some ideas.
To speak to your second point "The SaveLoad system isn't recording the items in each loadout slot...";
If the slots list is null, then it can't exactly be serialized, or rather, is serialized as an empty list.
I hope this helps. Let me know if I misinterpreted something.

First of all ... that's not actually correct. As the field is serialized when Unity creates the instance of Game the field is deserialized and initialized ... so regarding clean coding it is for sure not wrong to force initialize the fields but it is not really an issue here

The exceptions shouldn't be try - catched at all imho ... you want to get those and fix the underlying issue rather than catching the symptoms ... and then OP isn't serializing an array of GameObject at any point via the BinaryFormatter (note that also Json nor XML would not be able to do that either) ... OP is rather serializing a GameData which as far as I saw only contains base types

I tried to serialize a gameObject array at first, but figured out the binary formatter doesn't like that, so thats why its a string array now. Would it be better to have a universal UI, instantiate that, and reference the info from there to instantiate a 3d object in any scene I wanted?
